# Функция обработки

Tags: php, ооп, функции

Всем привет!
Осваиваю PHP и хочу понять как правильно предавать элемент для обработки в функцию.
Суть: из JS отправляется POST запрос, и возвращается в JSON-формате ответ. Форм много и постоянно писать гору кода чтобы проверять поля не удобно. Хочу к каждому полям(в примере типа "Имя") сделать функцию проверки. Не могу понять как это связать...

Есть функция:

```
function validateName($element = "NAME") {
  //Если поле "Имя" пустое
  if(!strlen($_POST[$element]) > 0 && !is_numeric($_POST[$element])) {
   $jsonData = array("status" => "ERROR", "field" => $element, "msg" => "Вы не заполнили поле");
  }
 return $jsonData;
}
```

И есть код который использует эту функцию и возвращает обратно в JS:

```
if(validateName("CONTACT_NAME")){
  //если поле не прошло проверку возвращаем обратно JSON
  $jsonData = validateName();
  exit(json_encode($jsonData));
}else{
   //продолжаем проверку других полей по цепочке
}
```

Не пойму, правильно ли делаю... JSON возвращает значение null

Comment: То есть данная функция проверяет только длину данных в переменной и то, что переменная является числом?

Comment: Суть не в проверке, а в передаче поля на проверку в функцию и получение обратно с JSON данными. 
@splash58 помог, правильный код ниже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в функции jsonData заполняется только, когда поле пустое

```
function noValidateName($element = "NAME") {

  $jsonData = false;  //  на случайб когда с полем все хорошо

  if(!strlen($_POST[$element]) && !is_numeric($_POST[$element])) {
    //Если поле "Имя" пустое
    $jsonData = array("status" => "ERROR", "field" => $element, "msg" => "Вы не заполнили поле");
  }
 return $jsonData;
}
```

и потом, в основном коде (кстати, функцию лучше переименовать, чтобы код был более читаемым

```
if($jsonData = notValidateName("CONTACT_NAME")) { // если все в порядке придет false
  //если поле не прошло проверку возвращаем обратно JSON
  exit(json_encode($jsonData));
}else{
   //продолжаем проверку других полей по цепочке
}
```

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо огромное!

Comment: рад помочь. Удачи!